# React Router v6.4+ Data API: Retry loader without displaying error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using react-router 6.21.1 and the new data api, I have routes setup like:

```
const routes = [
    {
        element: <RootWrapper/>,
        errorElement: <ErrorWrapper/>,
        children: [
            {path: "/login?", element: <LoginWrapper/>},
            {path: "/logout", element: <Logout/>},
            {
                id: "AuthenticatedRoot",
                element: <AuthenticatedRoot/>,
                children: [
                    // ...
                    {path: "/dashboard", element: <Dashboard/>, loader: fetchDashboard},
                ]
            }
        ]
]
```

My dashboard view is on display 24/7 and revalidates every 5 minutes. It needs to stay up through up to 5 errors to give at least 30 minutes for releases or other unknown downtimes. It was simple to do when doing manual useEffects for data fetching because I could just handle the error that returned from the fetch request:

```
await axios.get('dashboard')
    .then(
        response => {setData(response.data)},
        error => {
            setRetries(origRetries => {
                if (origRetries >= 6) {
                    setError(true)
                    setErrorMessage(error.message)
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return origRetries + 1
                }
            })
        }
    )
```

Is there anyway to do something like this with the new loaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your `fetchDashboard` loader function to close over the retry "state". An implementation may look similar to the following:

```js
const fetchDashboard = () => {
  let cache = {};
  let retry = 0;

  return async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get('dashboard');

      // Success, cache result and reset retry state
      cache = result;
      retry = 0;

      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      // Failure/error, increment retry count
      retry++;

      if (retry > 5) {
        // Rethrow error if ran out of retries
        throw error;
      } else {
        // Otherwise return cached result
        return cache;
      }
    }
  };
};
```

```
const routes = [
  {
    element: <RootWrapper />,
    errorElement: <ErrorWrapper />,
    children: [
      { path: "/login?", element: <LoginWrapper /> },
      { path: "/logout", element: <Logout /> },
      {
        id: "AuthenticatedRoot",
        element: <AuthenticatedRoot />,
        children: [
          // ...
          { 
            path: "/dashboard",
            element: <Dashboard />,
            errorElement: <Dashboard />, // <-- render as error element too!
            loader: fetchDashboard(),    // <-- invoke outer function
          },
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

```
import {
  useRouteError,
  useLoaderData,
  useNavigate,
  useNavigation
} from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { state } = useNavigation(); // "idle"/"loading", could be handy

  const data = useLoaderData();
  const error = useRouteError();

  // Effect to trigger route revalidation, 5-minute interval
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      navigate(".", { replace: true });
    }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-v6-4-data-api-retry-loader-without-displaying-error]

Comment: Thanks for writing this all up. I'll mark it as correct because I think this might be the only way to go about doing it as I had written the question up. I left out a couple of important caveats to keep it simple that make this solution not work for me but I think you've more or less answered that there's no clean or easy way to do it. I think for this one, I will just perform the initial fetch with the loader and then perform the subsequent reloads in useEffects.

Comment: @DivineSlayer That's more or less what my initial suggestion was going to be, and here's my initial testing [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-4-data-api-retry-loader-without-displaying-error-3xph9s) implementation before I thought about it a bit more to move the retry logic into the loader which I was able to get working "well enough".

Comment: @DivineSlayer That said, I'm still not a fan of, or sold on, the idea of these route loaders and prefer still using separate modules for fetching/loading data. If you happen to already be using Redux-Toolkit in your project, then a very viable solution might be to use its [Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) module and create an API slice. The queries can be customized to include [automatic retry behavior](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-retries) and because it's Redux the previous responses are all already cached by default.

Comment: I just went through the work to migrate my site over to the new loaders functionality and I'm not particularly impressed by it. There are a lot of edge cases that I need to handle that aren't supported and either require confusing/difficult code or just falling back on the old useEffect loader as I am doing here. I will look into those links you shared, thanks!

Comment: @DivineSlayer I totally agree. I think that for most apps that have already bought into using Redux for state management, and likely as part of data fetching/wrangling, integrating these route loaders feels a bit antithetic. I may be completely biased though. 